# How to display images from mongodb gridfs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to create a webApp where the users can upload some images, and for complete this task i'm using `gridfs`.

I frigured out how to save correctly them but the poblems start when i have to display them.

For save the images i use this code

**Save Images**

```
const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/upload_images";
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.connect(mongoURI);
const conn = mongoose.connection;

// Init gfs
let gfs;

conn.once('open', () => {
    // Init stream
    gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection('uploaded_images'); //collection name
});

// Create storage engine
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: 'uploaded_images' //collection name
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});
const upload = multer({ storage });

router.post('/posts', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {

    file = req.file;

    if(file){
        req.body.post.image_file = file.id;
    }

    Post.create(req.body.post, (err, post) => {
        if(err){
            res.redirect('/posts');
        } else {
            res.redirect('/posts');
        }
    });
});
```

and the images are saved correctly, now i have to display them.

I have a `mongoose` post schema where i save some datas and a reference of the uploaded image ( the ObjectId )

**Post Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    image_link: String,
    image_file: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'GFS'  
        }],
    brand: String,
    model: String,
    moto_type: String,
    date : {type : Date, default : Date.now}, 
    categories : [{
        title: String,
        content: String,
    }],
    comments: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Comment'  
        }],
    views: {type: String, default: '0'}
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema, 'posts');
```

And a gridfs schema for use the reference inside the post schema

**GridFs schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var gridFsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({});

module.exports = mongoose.model('GFS', gridFsSchema, 'uploaded_images.files');
```

My problems start when i try to display a post

```
router.get('/posts/:post_id', (req, res) => {

    post_id = req.params.post_id;

    Post.findById(post_id)
    .populate('comments')
    .populate('image_file')
    .exec((err, post) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
            res.redirect('/posts');
        } else {
            res.render('posts/show', {post: post})
        }
    });
});
```

The first problem is that the `.populate('image_file')` method throw this error

```
{ MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "GFS".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at new MissingSchemaError (/home/pero/motoWebApp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/missingSchema.js:22:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.model (/home/pero/motoWebApp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:925:11)
    at getModelsMapForPopulate (/home/pero/motoWebApp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4434:59)
    at populate (/home/pero/motoWebApp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3979:21)
    at _populate (/home/pero/motoWebApp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3949:5)
    at utils.promiseOrCallback.cb (/home/pero/motoWebApp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3924:5)
    at Object.promiseOrCallback (/home/pero/motoWebApp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:249:12)
    at Function.Model.populate (/home/pero/motoWebApp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3923:16)
    at model.Query.Query._completeOne (/home/pero/motoWebApp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2018:9)
    at Immediate.Query.base.findOne.call (/home/pero/motoWebApp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2057:10)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/pero/motoWebApp/node_modules/mquery/lib/utils.js:116:16)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
  message:
   'Schema hasn\'t been registered for model "GFS".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)',
  name: 'MissingSchemaError' }
```

The second is that i don't understand how to display the image when i make a get request to `/posts/:post_id`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very late, but this is to help anyone who wants an updated solution to this. Since the legacy Grid system is going to be deprecated, I am just sharing what worked for me. You can read more at the official MongoDB documentation.

```
import express from "express";
import mongoDB from "mongodb";
import assert  from "assert";

  
const dbName = "Your Database"
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
 
app.get('/image/:filename', (req, res) => {

 mongoDB.MongoClient.connect("Your Mongo Uri", 
  {
   useNewUrlParser:true,
   useUnifiedTopology:true
  },
 (error,client) => {

        assert.ifError(error)

        const db = client.db(dbName);

        var bucket = new mongoDB.GridFSBucket(db);

        bucket.openDownloadStreamByName(req.params.filename)
            .pipe(res)
    });

});




  

app.listen(4000, () => (console.log("Server Started on port 4000")));
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution that helped me server an image using GridFsBucket. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this:

For display the images correctly with gridfs You have to follow this steps:

**1)**

When you upload a file save the id as a referece in your Schema so that after you can populate it with the `.populate method`. You can save it as a reference by inserting this lines in the schema

```
image_file: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'GridFs' 
    },
```

**2)**

create a grifs model to use as referece for the uploaded files

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var GridfsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    filename: String
}, {strict: false});

module.exports = mongoose.model('GridFs', GridfsSchema, 'uploaded_images.files' );
```

The error that i had in the question was throw becouse i definde the model inside an external file and never imported it.

**3)**

define a route that render the files:

```
const express                   = require('express'),
      router                    = express.Router(),
      mongoose                  = require('mongoose'),
      path                      = require('path'),
      multer                    = require('multer'),
      crypto                    = require('crypto'),
      Grid                      = require('gridfs-stream'),
      GridFsStorage             = require('multer-gridfs-storage'),

      Post                      = require('../models/post');

const conn = mongoose.connection;
const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/moto_website";

// Init gfs
let gfs;

conn.once('open', () => {
    // Init stream
    gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection('uploaded_images'); //collection name
});

router.get('/image/:filename', (req, res) => {
    gfs.files.findOne({filename: req.params.filename}, (err, file) => {
        if(!file || file.length === 0){
            return res.status(404).json({err: 'No File Exists'});
        } else {
            // Check if is image
            if(file.contentType === "image/jpeg" || file.contentType === "image/png"){
                // Read output to broswer
                const readstream = gfs.createReadStream(file.filename);
                readstream.pipe(res);
            } else {
                res.status(404).json({err: 'Not and image'});
            }
        }
    });
});
```

now each time that you go at the path `/images/:image_name` it renders the image that has as name `:image_name`

**4)**

set as `src` attribute of your `<img>` tags the path `/images/<your_filename_in_gridfs.files>`

**Sources**

I had some errors before find the solution

1) I could retrive the populated objects but not theirs attributes that gave me undefined. That's becouse in the gridfs Schema i had an empty object so i could not retrive nothing. By defining in the `Schema` the attribute `filename: String` I solved it ( only for the filename attribute, the other attributes will return undefined. If you want to read them too you have to write them inside the `gridfs Schema` ). See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40505738/mongoose-cannot-access-populated-value)

2) I didn't know how to link the gridfs files to the relative reference [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073183/mongodb-populate-gridfs-files-metadata-in-parent-document)